# Pandas convert column where every cell is list of strings to list of integers

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-munging

I have a dataframe with columns that has list of numbers as strings:

```
C1 C2 l
1   3 ['5','9','1']
7   1 ['7','1','6']
```

What is the best way to convert it to list of ints?

```
C1 C2 l
1   3 [5,9,1]
7   1 [7,1,6]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```py
df['l'] = df['l'].apply(lambda lst: list(map(int, lst)))
```

```
print(df)

   C1  C2          l
0   1   7  [5, 9, 1]
1   3   1  [7, 1, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas' dataframes are not designed to work with nested structures such as lists. Thus, there is no vectorial method for this task.

You need to loop. The most efficient is to use a list comprehension (`apply` would also work but with much less efficiency).

```
df['l'] = [[int(x) for x in l] for l in df['l']]
```

*NB. There is no check. If you have anything that cannot be converted to integers, this will trigger an error!*

Output:

```
  C1 C2         l
0  1  3 [5, 9, 1]
1  7  1 [7, 1, 6]
```